# SELECT $id=$_GET['id']; Ничего не возвращает

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть следующий код, где $query должна возвращать цену, что собственно, не происходит. Вызывая код выводит id(?id=1, например) корректно. А как доходит до цикла(можно и без цикла, тоже не работает), вылазит ничего. Спасибо за внимание. 
PS: с функцией execute бился но ничего не понял, похоже.

```html
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting('E_ALL');//показ ошибок

 $host = 'localhost'; // имя хоста
 $database = 'test_sql'; // имя базы данных
 $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
 $pswd = ''; //  пароль
 $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");//соединение с бд
 mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");


 $id = $_GET['id'];//получаем id(?id=some id)
 $query = "SELECT 'price' FROM 'oc_product' WHERE 'product_id' = $id";//выгрузка из таблицы
 $res = mysql_query($query);//вроде как возвращает id из $query
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);//вызов массива или поля. Сюда передаем $res как параметр. Выдает массив(mysql_fetch_array). Значение поля(mysql_fetch_row)
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  echo "Цена: ".$row."<br>";//вывод цены
 }

?> 
 <!-- проверка id -->
 <div><?php echo $id; ?></div>
```

Comment: echo "Цена: ".$row['price']."<br>";

Comment: и два раза mysql_fetch_array не имеет смысла делать, row уже обюычный массив, который можно перебрать циклом for например.

Comment: По порядку. 1) Перестаньте использовать **mysql_***. Его поддержка прекращена и оно удалено из врсий 7+. 2) У вас SQL injection. 3) Что за значение у $query?

Comment: Антон, нет, не работает.

Comment: E_p, как это можно еще реализовать? про 3й пункт не понял, в каком смысле?

Comment: после строки $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) сделайте var_dump($row) что в итоге?

Comment: правильно  `echo "Цена: ".$row[0]."<br>"; ` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Jean-Claude , выводит null

Comment: Jean-Claude, смотрел, но это(ваше предложение) ничего не меняет.

Comment: Попробуйте перед while добавить строку: var_dump($row); Что выдаст? Да, и цикл нужно по row пустить к примеру foreach ($row as $key => $value) { echo "Цена: " . $value . "<br>"; }

Comment: почему у вас имена полей и таблицы в запросе в обычных апострофах ? в MySQL поля и таблицы можно писать без кавычек, или в _обратных_ апострофах, но никак не в обычных. И посмотрите примеры использования query, там везде есть проверка на ошибки, которую вы почему то не делаете, поэтому не знаете, что у вас ошибки в синтаксисе SQL ... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: И да, не надо обучаться работе с устаревшими функциями mysql_ через пару лет вам придется начать переписывать все, что вы сейчас напишите с использованием современных средств (mysqli, pdo)

Comment: @Mike в phpmyadmin работает, просто выводит столбец price при выполнении запроса SELECT 'price' FROM.... ))

Comment: Mike, Jean-Claude спасибо. Ошибка была в обратных апострофах и в не указанной переменной $row[0]. Спасибо за внимание. Просто даже не знал, что в mySql есть отдельный вывод ошибок. В тему "sql не безопасно" могли бы посоветовать как обыграть эту ситуацию?

Comment: @ВладЮдкин Что бы было безопасно, используйте таки нормальные средства работы с БД (mysqi или pdo) и привязку переменных (ссылки давал в предыдущем вашем вопросе)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Вы видимо только колонку в кавычки заключили, конечно оно слово price вернет, вы еще имя таблицы заключите в кавычки ...

Comment: @Mike, еще раз благодарю, буду вникать

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что у вас в базе пока по одной строке с ценами на товары. А выборка в скрипте делается минимум дважды. При этом первый результат он отбрасывает.

Я исправил скрипт, удалив лишнее. Попробуйте так:

```html
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting('E_ALL');//показ ошибок

 $host = 'localhost'; // имя хоста
 $database = 'test_sql'; // имя базы данных
 $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
 $pswd = ''; //  пароль
 $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");//соединение с бд
 mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");


 $id = $_GET['id'];//получаем id(?id=some id)
 $query = "SELECT 'price' FROM 'oc_product' WHERE 'product_id' = $id";//выгрузка из таблицы
 $res = mysql_query($query);//вроде как возвращает id из $query
 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  echo "Цена: ".$row[0]."<br>";//вывод цены
 }

?> 
 <!-- проверка id -->
 <div><?php echo $id; ?></div>
```

Также обратите внимание, что расширение MySQL устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Рекомендуется вместо него использовать расширения MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.